# Is there any geocoding for better international support?

Tags: data, geocoding, database, web-service, chinese

I need international support database with Chinese and English, do you know any data provide both? (So far, I found only Google Map and MaxMind is okay;  Open Street Map just poorly supported data; any better solution?)

Comment: This question is subjective, which means every answer could be equally valid, which means this is not really a good question for this site.

Answer (score 7):

<strike>Finally I found the service best shoot my need, Here MAP API. They support mulitiple language and has good zh-hant/zh-hans matching; eventhough, they don't have compelete translate, but well matched, better then Google Map Serivce.</strike>

**Update** Google map is still the best one; during my using the HERE MAP API, I found a lot of cities are missmatched in Chinese ("台北" might be just an exception, "旧金山", "洛杉矶" ... those important cities are missing!). The missing rate of HERE MAP is higher than Google Map, so Google MAP is still the best one!

**For Google map is blocked in China issue**

Someone might want to know how to access Google Map Service in China. For me, I just use Mapbox (They are using Open Street Map resource, but beautifully rendered; more important, it could be accessed in China, the 2nd large internet market in the world). For presenting map, I use Google Map as a data service underneath (we would have a service outside of China, and it could connect the Google Map Service as well); thus, the geodata would be rich and accurate and the map would still present very well in China (I can't tell the speed, but at least it works; as Baidu Map or QQ Map don't have global support service).

Again, here is my list of service I have found for your reference.

```
| Service Name  | Free Limit | Lowest Rate       | Note                            |
| OpenCageData  | 2.k/day    | $50/mo            |                                 |
| IP-API        | 150/min    |                   | Low request rate                |
| GeoPlugin     | 120/min    | 15Eur/mo ~ 2m/day | Stack-overflow Best Rated       |
| smart-ip.net  | 5k/day     | Unkown            |                                 |
| ipinfo.io     | 1k/day     | $50/mo ~ 10k/day  |                                 |
| snoopi.io     | 14k/day    | $20/mo ~ 100k/day | 2015 yr 8 Aug Relase Beta       |
| PICKPOINT.io  | 2.5k/day   |                   | Data Source: OpenStreetMap      |
| HostIP.info   |            |                   | Data Source: MaxMind            |
| Yahoo!        |            | $8/1000/query     | Expensive, and poorly supported |
| Google Map    | 1k/day     |                   | Doesn't support Asian very well |
| Free Geo IP   | 10k/hr     | Free              | Data Source: MaxMind            |
| MapQuest      | 15k/mo     | $99/mo            | Data Source: OpenStreetMap      |
| Sina Geo API  | Unkown     | Unkown            | Need long time verification     |
| HERE MAP API  | 10k/mo     | $59/mo ~ 15k/mo   | Facebook officially using       |
| Baidu Map API | Unlimited  | Unkown            | It has data for China only      |
```

Comment: Can you post a few addresses that are giving you troubles.  I'll check a few geocoders and see what the verdict is.

Answer (score 2):

I know of a list of Online geocodes that was put together by a the University of Texas A&M in the United State.

Most of the geocoding service support in English, I did see one in Japanese, at first glance I haven't found anything in Chinese on the website.

It provides a list of geocodes from free access to pay services. Keep in mind it has not been update since 2013, but I've tried a few and are still linked properly.

Here is the [link](https://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/Geocode/OtherGeocoders/)

Comment: thanks, and I found a service closed to my need. HERE MAP